# Using Nhibernate without hitting the database for a certain type of class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, caching

I am working on an application that uses Nhibernate with SysCache as a second level cache.

All the types that we Get or Save using Nhibernate are stored in the database, what I am trying to do is using the second level cache to store and update a certain type of object and saving it in the database only at the end of day. 
This object type is recomputed from DB at first and then updated by different actions after that, it is often used by the application and that's the reason why we prefer to store it in DB at the end of day and not every time it's modified.

And to ensure objects consistency I would like to use Nhibernate because when a child of this object is updated, the reconstructed object will be up to date also.

So is there a way to tell Nhibernate that for a certain type of object it doesn't need to store it in DB, only in the cache and work with it only from the cache ?

I don't now if it's clear, I am frensh so excuse my poor english :)

Thanks

Comment: Question is why should nhibernate know about that object if you don't want to have it persisted in the database at all?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. The object will be saved but only at the end of day.

Comment: What happens if the app pool cycles, surely you will lose what has been updated?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at interceptor, this will enable you to intercept the save before you go to the database. And return a different value onload as is in the database:

[nhibernate-interceptor-magic-tricks-the-example](http://blog.scooletz.com/2011/02/24/nhibernate-interceptor-magic-tricks-the-example/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't see how can I use the methods provided by IInterceptor to prevent persistence of the object in the database.
The IsTransient method only indicates if the object has to be inserted or updated in databse.
Also OnLoad and OnSave methods are executed to change the state of the object and cannot prevent persistence in database ...